# Html.DropdownlistFor not showing in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have this line in my view.aspx I am not using razor:

```
 <p style="color:Red">
        <% Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AllSundays, new SelectList(Model.AllSundays)); %>
  </p>
```

When I run my program and view source there is nothing there.
I am making use of the ViewModel in my action I have:

```
 var allSundaysInThisMonth = new SundaysInMonthViewModel
  {
    AllSundays = sundays.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
      Value = x.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
      Text = x.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
    })
  };

  var selectedSunday = new SundaysInMonthViewModel{
    SelectedSunday = thisMonthSundays.Where(x => x < now)
    .Last().ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
  };

  return View(allSundaysInThisMonth);
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `<%=` and no comma at the end if you want to output something to the response, otherwise you are only executing server side code that never gets flushed to the response:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.AllSundays, 
    new SelectList(Model.AllSundays)
) %>
```

Also `AllSundays` seems to already be an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so you don't need to feed that to a `SelectList` in the view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.AllSundays, 
    Model.AllSundays
) %>
```

Also (and this is extremely important), you should not use the same property as both the selected value and the available values. Currently you are using `AllSundays` twice. That's absolutely wrong. The DropDownList helper expects as first argument a scalar property on your view model to hold the selected value and an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property as second argument that will hold the selected values.

So what you want is:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.SelectedSunday, 
    Model.AllSundays
) %>
```

Comment: Sorry yes I forgot the,in my case, <%: and also the parameter list was wrong, it should be: <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSunday, Model.AllSundays) %>  thanks!

Comment: almost, the default is not 12/08/2012 but 22/07/2012 which is incorrect, so the code in the controller/action is not correct for var selectedSunday.

Comment: I fixed it: var sundays =  thisMonthSundays.Concat(lastMonthSundays.Skip(Math.Max(0, lastMonthSundays.Count() - sundaysToTakeFromLastMonth)).Take(sundaysToTakeFromLastMonth)); the concat was at the end I appended it to the front and that took care of it...i hope...

Comment: @charlie_cat, OK, do you have some other questions about this post or you might consider closing the thread?